# ¿Como puedo organizar una tabla mysql según valores de dos columnas en la misma tabla?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

¡Hola a todos!, veran, tengo una tabla llamada "menu" que contiene dos columnas, una llamada ID (la id del menu, es decir el menu principal) y la otra IdPadre (para saber de que menu pertenece, es decir submenu), pues bien, lo que intento hacer es una cosulta que me organice los registros de tal manera que me quede primero las filas independiente (es decir menu principal) seguido de las filas que dependen de el, les pongo un ejemplo

Esta es mi tabla....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, los submenu (Cargas, Devoluciones,Entregas) con IdPadre 1 (marcado en rojo) pertenecen al menu Movimientos (Id 1) lo mismo con los submenu en azul.

Pero yo quiero organizarlos de tal forma que me queden asi...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Notese que el submenu "Entregas" cambia de posición.**

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me ofrezcan, he intentado de todo y buscado info en otras partes, no se de que manera lo pudiera hacer, si de algo ayuda estoy realizando la consulta desde Web Service c#. Muchas Gracias

Comment: Sería bueno que añadieses qué consulta estás haciendo ahora, qué resultados obtienes y por qué no funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con esta consulta, suponiendo que la tabla se llama `TablaMenu`:

```
SELECT Id, Nombre, IdPadre, IF(IdPadre = 0, Id, IdPadre) AS pos 
FROM TablaMenu ORDER BY pos ASC, IdPadre ASC
```

La cual da este resultado:

```
Id  Nombre         IdPadre   pos
 1  Movimientos        0      1
 2  Cargas             1      1
 3  Devoluciones       1      1
 6  Entregas           1      1
 4  Configuracion      0      4
 5  Usuarios           4      4
 7  Administradores    4      4
```

Esta consulta hace una columna temporal `pos` que trabaja comparando los valores de `Id` e `IdPadre` para hacer una especie de agrupador que ayude a ordenar los resultados como lo necesitas. Ignora esta columna temporal y tienes el resultado esperado.

Comment: ¡WOOW! ¡PERFECTO! eres un genio, muchísimas gracias me funciono a la perfección